# Computing the generator and error polynomials of a $\left[15, 7, 5\right]$ BCH code

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, coding-theory

My question: Let $\alpha$ be a root of $1+x+x^4 \in \text{F}_{2}\left[x\right]$ and let C be a narrow-sense BCH code with length 15, and designed distance 5.

Find the generator polynomial of $C$ and determine the error position of $100000111000000$.

My work so far:

If $\alpha$ is a root of $1+x+x^4 \in \text{F}_{2}\left[x\right]$ and $C$ is a narrow-sense BCH code with parameters with length 15 and designed distance 5, then a generator polynomial is

$g\left(x\right)=\text{lcm}\left(1+x+x^4\right)\left(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4\right)=1+x^4+x^6+x^7+x^8$

and we also noted that this code will be able to correct 2 errors, from the equation for designed distance $d=2\delta +1$, and because the degree of $g\left(x\right)$ is $8$, we will have a $\left[15, 7, 5\right]$ narrow-sense BCH code.

Now in order to decode the received word $w\left(x\right)=\left(w_{0}+w_{1}x+...+w_{n-1}x^{n-1}\right)=100000111000000$, first we check

$w\left(x\right)H^{T}=0$, where $H$ is the parity check matrix given by

\begin{bmatrix}1 & \alpha & \alpha^{2} &. . . & \alpha^{14} \\1 & \alpha^{3} & \alpha^{9}&...&\alpha^{12} \end{bmatrix}

and if $w\left(x\right)H^{T}=0$ we conclude that there is no error. If $w\left(x\right)H^{T} \neq 0$, next we calculate the syndromes $\left(s_{0}, s_{1}, ..., s_{\delta-2}\right)=\left(w_{0}, w_{1}, ..., w_{n-1}\right)H^{T}$, where $s_{i}=e\left(\alpha^{i+1}\right)$ is the error locator polynomial.

Because we have a two error pattern, we will need to find the error polynomial to decode $c\left(x\right)=w\left(x\right)-e\left(x\right)$.

We do this in the following way.

First we consider the system of equations

\begin{align*}
  \alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= \,s_{1} \\ 
  \alpha_{1}^{3}+\alpha_{2}^{3} &= \, s_{2} \\ 
\end{align*}

and noting $$\alpha_{1}^{3}+\alpha_{2}^{3}=\underbrace{\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\right)}_{s_{1}} \underbrace{\left(\alpha_{1}^{2}+\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}+\alpha_{2}^{2}\right)}_{s^{2}_{1}+\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}}$$

Then, rewriting the two equations for $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$,

\begin{align*}
  \alpha_{1} + \alpha_{2} &= \,s_{1} \\ 
  \alpha_{1}^{3} \cdot \alpha_{2}^{3} &= \, s_{2}s_{1}^{-1}+s_{1}^{2}=\frac{s_{2}+s_{1}^{3}}{s_{1}} \\ 
\end{align*}

and finally we construct a quadratic equation whose roots are $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$,

$\left(x-\alpha_{1}\right)\left(x-\alpha_{2}\right)=x^2-\left(\alpha_{1}+\alpha_{2}\right)+\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}=x^2+s_{1}x+\frac{s_{2}+s_{1}^{3}}{s_{1}}$.

What is giving me trouble:

So after all of this my question is really where to go from here. Do I simply solve the quadratic equations for the roots of $x^2+s_{1}x+\frac{s_{2}+s_{1}^{3}}{s_{1}}$, or is there another detail I am missing? As always, thanks for the help.

Comment: A typo $\alpha_1^2+\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_2^2=s_1^2+\alpha_1\alpha_2$! Anyway, the point here is to write the product $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ in terms of the syndromes, and end up with $\alpha_1\alpha_2=(s_2+s_1^3)/s_1$. So the quadratic in the end is correct.

Comment: Ahh I see. So I don't need to solve for the quadratic, I need to get the product $\alpha_{1}\alpha_{2}$ in terms of the syndromes?

Comment: Anyway, you do want to solve that quadratic to find the error locations. There are special cases. 1) May be only one error occurred? This is not really a problem because this shows as the possibility $\alpha_2=0$, which happens if and only if $s_2=s_1^3$. 2) The quadratic may not have solutions in $\Bbb{F}_{16}$. This is an indication that more than two errors occured, and there is nothing much you can do about it.

Comment: Ohhh I understand now. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Over the field $\Bbb{F}_{2^m}$ the quadratic $$x^2+ax+b=0$$ has two roots if and only if $a\neq0$ and $tr(b/a^2)=0$, where $tr(z)$ stands for the trace.

Comment: IIRC some practical decoder implementations resort to the so called Chien search, where you basically test consecutive powers of $\alpha$ for being zeros of the error locator polynomial $E(x)$, and flip the corresponding received bit when you find one. This is not as dumb as it sounds, because there are recurrence relations satisfied by $E(\alpha^i)$ making it more efficient. If you do that, you need to keep track that your search found a sufficient number of zeros of $E(x)$.

Comment: There is the further point that the quadratic formula does not work in characteristic two, so solving those zeros algebraically is a bit strange. You can use the so called half-trace, but I'm not sure that is very efficient either. If Dilip Sarwate shows up, he can comment.

Comment: That is so cool! Thank you for the feedback, you always leave very helpful/motivating comments. I really appreciate the help. I will try to locate the errors and post what I discover.

Comment: The Chien search is a very _practical_ method for finding which bits are in error and _correcting_ the erroneous bits (which is just  "flipping" the bit in question) because the determination that a specific bit is in error is done just as the bit is ready to leave the decoder, and if the bit is incorrect, _flipping_ the bit on its way out of the decoder into the cold gray world outside. It is not a very useful method for mathematicians working out the answers with paper and pencil. Berlekamp's _Algebraic Coding Theory_ discusses the solution of quadratics over fields of characteristic 2.

Comment: I will have to find a copy. Do you know of any software that is available so that I can check my work more easily? Working with small codes with pencil and paper is fine, but anything like $GF\left(16\right)$ and beyond quickly gets very difficult for me and it would be nice to have a way to check my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking the comments above into consideration, I believe I have found the solution.

So, using the transpose of $H$,

$$H^{T} =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}  $$,

and setting $w\left(x\right)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 &0 &0& 1& 1& 1& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$

then $$w\left(x\right)H^{T}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}^T=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\
1\\
0\\
0\\
1\\
1\\
1\\
1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha^{4}\\
\alpha^{12}\\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
s_{1}\\
s_{2}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Now solving for $x^2+s_{1}x+\frac{s_{2}+s_{1}^{3}}{{s_{1}}}=0$,

$$x^2+\alpha^{4}x+\frac{\alpha^{12}+\left(\alpha^{4}\right)^{3}}{\alpha^{4}}=0$$

$$\implies x^2+\alpha^{4}+2\alpha^{8}=x^2+\alpha^{4}$$

is the error check polynomial.

We can check this with $$s\left(x\right)=\left(x-\alpha^{2}\right)\left(x-\alpha^{2}\right)=x^2+\alpha^4$$

So taking this into consideration we can conclude that the errors were in the fourth and twelfth positions.